# Deleting rows from dataframe, where values is ' n/a'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
1.8      4017,

n/a     3956, 

2        3243,

1.95     2984,

1.85     2791,

2.05     2777,
```

This is the value counts for one of my column. As you can see, the 2nd most common is ' n/a'.
I want to delete all rows from my dataset, where the value in that column is ' n/a'.

I tried `df.dropna(subset=['colname'] , inplace = True]`  but did not work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that non-numeric values are assigned `NaN` values:

```
df['colname'] = pd.to_numeric(df['colname'], errors='coerce')
```

`n/a` looks like it might be a string instead of `NaN` (which is a floating-point value).

Then

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['colname'])
```

should work as expected.

Comment: This is a good stab, but I tried this with read_csv and it does indeed interpret n/a as NaN when reading in. My best guess would be OP calls `dropna` but doesn't assign the result back. Your answer covers all the bases anyway, so that's great.